# R: Create a function within a function, passing arguments as defaults

Tags: r, function, lexical-scope

I am developing a function that returns another function of a particular form (linear or asymptotic, indicated by the "FuncType" argument). I would like to assign a vector of default values to the "params" argument of the function to be returned.

```
# FuncType is either "lin" or "asymp"
# params is a numerical vector of parameters (length 3 if FuncType is "lin", 
# length 4 if FuncType is "asymp")

GenerateFunc <- function(FuncType = "lin", params) {

  # Linear case: m (slope), b (intercept), and err (error)
  if (FuncType == "lin") {
    outfunc <- function(x, params){
    m <- params[1]
    b <- params[2]
    err <- params[3]
    outval <- m*x + b + rnorm(1, 0, err)
    return(outval)
    }
  }

  # Asymptotic case: a (slope), b (curvature), c (rate of convergence), and err (error)
  if (FuncType == "asymp") {
    outfunc <- function(x, params){
    a <- params[1]
    b <- params[2]
    c <- params[3]
    err <- params[4]
    outval <- (a * x) / (b*x + c) + rnorm(1, 0, err)
    return(outval)
    }
  }

 return(outfunc)
}
```

"GenerateFunc" creates the desired function but does not pass "params" to "outfunc" as a default argument:

```
myfunc <- GenerateFunc("asymp", params = rep(1,4))
myfunc(x = 10)

Error in myfunc(x = 10) : argument "params" is missing, with no default
```

Many thanks in advance for your guidance.

Cheers,
Nate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t use `params` as a default argument because you don’t tell it to!

You just need to do this — you need to change the name though, specifying a default parameter as `params = params` won’t work.

```
GenerateFunc <- function(FuncType = "lin", params) {
    defaults <- params

    if (FuncType == "lin") {
        outfunc <- function(x, params = defaults) {
            m <- params[1]
            b <- params[2]
            err <- params[3]
            m*x + b + rnorm(1, 0, err)
        }
    }

    … etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had unsuccessfully tried "params = params" earlier but forgot to include that in my reproducible version.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't passed the `params` argument going in to `GenerateFunc` as default values for the `params` argument in `outfunc`. Might be less confusing (and actually necessary to avoid a recursive error) to give the default params a different name. Here I call it '`paramsdefault`':

```
GenerateFunc <- function(FuncType = "lin", paramsdefault) {

  # Linear case: m (slope), b (intercept), and err (error)
  if (FuncType == "lin") {
    outfunc <- function(x, params = paramsdefault){
      m <- params[1]
      b <- params[2]
      err <- params[3]
      outval <- m*x + b + rnorm(1, 0, err)
      return(outval)
    }
  }

  # Asymptotic case: a (slope), b (curvature), c (rate of convergence), and err (error)
  if (FuncType == "asymp") {
    outfunc <- function(x, params = paramsdefault){
      a <- params[1]
      b <- params[2]
      c <- params[3]
      err <- params[4]
      outval <- (a * x) / (b*x + c) + rnorm(1, 0, err)
      return(outval)
    }
  }

  return(outfunc)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!